Could not install any packages using NPM, node version is incorrect
I have a react app. whenever I try to install any package it gives me following error
 sudo npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm WARN cli npm v10.2.5 does not support Node.js v19.3.0. This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.10.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.3.0', npm: '10.2.5' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/parser@7.10.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.3.0', npm: '10.2.5' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/scope-manager@7.10.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.3.0', npm: '10.2.5' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/type-utils@7.10.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.3.0', npm: '10.2.5' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/types@7.10.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.3.0', npm: '10.2.5' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@7.10.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.3.0', npm: '10.2.5' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/utils@7.10.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.3.0', npm: '10.2.5' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/visitor-keys@7.10.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.3.0', npm: '10.2.5' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'vite@5.2.11',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.0.0 || >=20.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.3.0', npm: '10.2.5' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

up to date, audited 296 packages in 3s

66 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

I have tried using nvm which shows the following output
       v18.17.0
->     v18.18.0
         system
default -> lts/* (-> N/A)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v18.18.0) (default)
stable -> 18.18 (-> v18.18.0) (default)
lts/* -> lts/iron (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.21.3 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.20.2 (-> N/A)
lts/hydrogen -> v18.20.3 (-> N/A)
lts/iron -> v20.14.0 (-> N/A)

there were initally v21.4.0 and v20.10.0 which I removed but still npm does not work.
this is my package.json file
{
  "name": "controls",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && vite",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.2.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  }
}

Does anyone have any idea how can I fix this

First thing you can try is to check the node version by running
node --version command.
When I see the nvm list from your post, The default one shown by the NVM which is lts and not exactly the v18
the following warning indicates that you are using v19.3.0 of node with npm v10.2.5
npm WARN cli npm v10.2.5 does not support Node.js v19.3.0. 
this is the cause of the error
to fix this make sure you have the correct npm and node versions on your system
you can check here for the list of node versions linked with npm
https://nodejs.org/dist/index.json
I hope this will help :)
